# Git force-push with wrong account

Tags: github

I added a few commits to a branch that I just created locally, squashed them and force-pushed to remote. But when I check on github web UI, it says that I "added the commit" and another person "force-pushed". But the only git account I have ever configured in my terminal is my own git account.
If I do `git log` locally, the commits have correct username and email (me). It seems that it's only pushing with another person's account, but I don't understand why. Is it because I used to git `reset --hard` to this person's commit on another branch and this reset somehow changed some configuration of my git? How can I fix this and make github UI show the right person who pushed the commits?

Comment: GitHub literally cannot see your Git configuration. They can see only the things you give to them: the commit contents, and any https or ssh logins you make. If it says someone else did a force-push, they're guessing based on https login or ssh key.

Answer (score 0):

> . It seems that it's only pushing with another person's account, but I don't understand why

That would not have anything to do with commit authorship.

It would involve your authentication when pushing: in case of HTTPS URL, check if your credential manager does have the wrong account cached.

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https"|git credential-$(git config credential.helper) get
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran `ssh -vT git@github.com`. Turns out I was logged in as someone else with a wrong id_rsa file.